# Inteliji idea не видит Jsoup

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: Inteliji idea не видит теги от jsoup]

Inteliji idea не видит теги от jsoup.

Answer (score -1):

Библиотека подключена правильно (строка импорта). Проблема, скорее всего, в этом : jsoup – это непонятно что: такого объекта не объявлено.

Правильно будет вот так:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse("...");
```

Здесь у класса Jsoup (название с заглавной буквы) вызывается статический метод parse(...).
Попробуйте так.